# Uploading files directly to specific folder in ftp server using spring spring

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

I have, I suppose, really newbie question but the fact is I'm newbie in spring framework. 
How can I upload files to, for example 'upload' folder loceted in root directory of my ftp server? 
I have tried this:
My application context file:

```
<bean id="ftpClientFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <property name="username" value="test"/>
    <property name="password" value="test"/>
    <property name="clientMode" value="0"/>
    <property name="fileType" value="2"/>
    <property name="bufferSize" value="10000"/>                 
</bean>

<int:channel id="ftpChannel"/>

<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="outFtpAdapter"
                                channel="ftpChannel"
                                session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                                remote-directory="/Users/test"/>
```

and my java code:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
            new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/citrus/resources/citrus-context.xml");
    MessageChannel ftpChannel = context.getBean("ftpChannel", MessageChannel.class);
    File file = new File("/Users/test/test.txt");
    Message<File> fileMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();
    ftpChannel.send(fileMessage);
    context.close();
```

But this example upload files to root directory. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested it and work well:

```
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter
                id="sendFileToServer"
                auto-create-directory="true"
                session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
                remote-directory="/Users/test"/>
```

Where my FTP server is an embedded one and its root is:

```
[MY_USER_HOME]\Temp\junit7944189423444999123\FtpServerOutboundTests\
```

So the file is stored in the dir:

```
[MY_USER_HOME]\Temp\junit7944189423444999123\FtpServerOutboundTests\Users\test\
```

It is with the latest Spring Integration version.

Which is your version?

Comment: My version is 2.1.6
But I'm not sure if I understand everything correctly. If I have, for example folder 'upload' in localhost server, I should in remote-directory give "/upload" right? Don't know why I thought that remote-directory specified path from witch I want to upload files. 
Correct me please if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ok, I know what I was doing wrong. Thanks for answer. You really cleared that for me :)

Comment: Oh! Good to know. You saved my time to explain it for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using FTPClient upload MultipartFiles to apache FTP server
[useful repo](https://github.com/Janitham97/SpringFTPFileUpload)
Hope this help for future search.