# Unable to autowire MessageChannel in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-boot, ftp, spring-integration, message-channel

I'm trying out FTP file upload and download example using spring integration. I want to manually upload a file to the outputChannel. I don't want invoke it when there is a change in inputChannel. So, the FTPApplication should just have a declaration for the outputChannel bean. Im refering this article [Uploading files directly to specific folder in ftp server using spring spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694655/uploading-files-directly-to-specific-folder-in-ftp-server-using-spring-spring) for this purpose(Only for manually uploading and this way is common in most pages). Below is the Spring boot application code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FtpApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FtpApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> ftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("localhost");
        sf.setPort(21);
        sf.setUsername("root");
        sf.setPassword("root");
        return new CachingSessionFactory<FTPFile>(sf);
    }

    @Bean
    public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer fileSynchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(ftpSessionFactory());
        fileSynchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(false);
        fileSynchronizer.setRemoteDirectory("/");
        fileSynchronizer.setFilter(new FtpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xml"));
        return fileSynchronizer;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value="inputChannel", channel = "inputChannel")
    public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                ftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("ftp-inbound"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel")
    public MessageHandler handler() {
        return new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                System.out.println(message.getPayload());
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(10));
        return pollerMetadata;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value="outputChannel", channel = "outputChannel")
    public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource1() {
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource source = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(
                ftpInboundFileSynchronizer());
        source.setLocalDirectory(new File("ftp-outbound"));
        source.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        source.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return source;
    }

}
```

The controller code is as shown below:

```
@RestController
public class FTPController {

    @Autowired
    MessageChannel outputChannel;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ftpuploadtest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getM36Messages() {
        File file = new File("ftp.txt");
        Message<File> fileMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();
        outputChannel.send(fileMessage);
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get the following error:

```
Description:
Field outputChannel in com.ftp.FTPController required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - nullChannel: defined in null
    - errorChannel: defined in null
    - inputChannel: a programmatically registered singleton

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you made some mistake around `outputChannel` component.

If that is about **upload**, so you have to use `@ServiceActivator` and `FtpMessageHandler`.

On the other hand for such a problem you have to declare `@Bean` for the `outputChannel` and together with the `@Autowired`, in the `FTPController`, you should add `@Qualifier("outputChannel")`.

Comment: You also shouldn't use the same synchronizer in two inbound channel adapters.

Comment: @Artem: If I use ServiceActivator annotation, I need to mention an inputChannel. Here I want to manually upload the file to an output channel. It shouldn't be called when there is a change in input channel. What am I supposed to do? That is the reason why I didn't go to SeviceActivator annotation. Pardon me, if I'm sounding you very stupid.

Comment: Please, explain the task then. It is fully unclear why you treat message channel as something for upload.

Comment: @ArtemBilan: Sorry Sir. Updated the question.

Comment: One more time `FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` is for downloading files from FTP. You have to use `FtpMessageHandler` for uploading. Yes , for this purpose you can send message with file payload and `@ServiceActivator` will do the stuff for you. Please, read more about FTP support in the Reference Manual

Comment: If we are talking about that sample you refer, indeed `@ServiceActivator` is used in Java Config instead of`<outbound-channel-adapter>`

Comment: @ArtemBilan: Yes, the xml version I've got working for send. I don't want to rewrite the reading portion in xml. So, I'm trying to write the send/write portion in java config. As I see, there is less hep available for java config.

Comment: Here http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound. As you see help is there...

Answer (score 0):

use @Qualifier , with @Autowired . and keep the variable name same as bean name.